Magento2.4.6: How to apply Security/Quality patches to magento open source?
My website is on magento2.4.6 open source and I want to apply all security/quality patches available to date.
Where I can find all the patches list and how to apply them?

To update this is my path... We need composer version 2.2.??. Originally my composer was v2.7
#composer self-update 2.2.21
Back up file system.
And Magento DB
Create a backup of composer.json & .lock files.
#cp composer.json composer-backup.json
#cp composer.lock composer-backup.lock
Disable Magento cache.
#php bin/magento cache: disable
Put Magento into maintenance mode.
#php bin/magento maintenance: enable
The -w flag (--with-dependencies) allows composer to update the main package with dependencies.
#composer require-commerce magento/product-community-edition 2.4.6-p6 -w
#composer update
run setup: upgrade compile deploy etc
#rm -rf pub/static/; rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/; rm -rf generated/code/*; php bin/magento setup:upgrade && bin/magento setup:di:compile && bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f && bin/magento cache: flush
Finish off with
#php bin/magento --version           // check Magento version
#redis-cli flushall async            // flush redis cache
#php bin/magento maintenance:disable // disable maintenance
#php bin/magento deploy:mode:show    // check which mode we are in now.
#php bin/magento cache:enable        // re-enable cache
// Test website.
// If needed.
#bin/magento deploy:mode:set production // Change to production mode

You can found app patches list from here :
https://experienceleague.adobe.com/tools/commerce-quality-patches/index.html
You can able to apply the patches as mention here :
https://github.com/magento/quality-patches
